# How do I prevent desktop shortcuts from being made in Windows?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, desktop, file-shortcut

It is a common practice to have installers place shortcuts *by default* on the desktop, but most installers allow you to disable this by unchecking the appropriate checkbox. There are also installers (like Adobe Creative Cloud updates) that don't have an option to **not** place a shortcut on the desktop. I *really* hate desktop shortcuts but I still want to use my desktop for temporary files, quick management, etc. Is there any way I can automatically hide shortcuts (*.lnk files) on my desktop?

Comment: There's an option to hide all desktop icons somewhere.

Comment: I can't imagine there's a solution that doesn't present more problems than it fixes. If you run installers under a different usercode then the shortcuts will be on the desktop of that user so you won't see them (unless it's creates the shortcut for all users). However, installing programs as a user other than you will give you lots of hassle. I would turn the question around and ask you why manually deleting the occasional shortcut is such a hardship?

Comment: Basically, all I'm asking for is how to automatically hide *.lnk files, and definitely nothing more. I still want a useable desktop with icons.

Comment: @dylanweber: If all you want to do is hide the files (which is not at all what the question title implies), just create a scheduled task that regularly runs a batch file that hides `Desktop\*.lnk`

Comment: Thanks for this question, Dylan. These unwanted icons that we have to delete after every update are the ultimate display of disrespect by software developers such as Adobe, Google et al. 

Have you ever found a good, easy, reliable solution?

Comment: @Ralf I have not but I assume it could be done with a script and a schedule but I only have experience in Linux and macOS so I decided to just live with it.

Answer (score 3):

First, make a copy of your desktop (e.g. DesktopCopy folder containing the shortcuts you want on the desktop) and put it in the documents folder (or another user defined folder).

Secondly, create a batch file which will copy (and overwrite!) your desktop with the files from the DesktopCopy folder). You can use the mirror function of robocopy deleting files not present in the source directory.

Then, with the task scheduler create a task (CopyDesktopContents), which starts at windows start up or logging in and which runs the batch.

If you want to add your own shortcuts on your desktop, just do so and again copy the contents of your desktop to the DesktopCopy folder, so that next time you (or another user) starts up the computer or logs in, the new copy will be used by the batch file.

Comment: Reasonably neat solution but it still requires maintenance - if you install something you want a shortcut for, and you forget to update the DesktopCopy folder, you will wipe the new shortcut(s). Perhaps the script should compare first, notify of differences and give you a choice of whether to update the baseline with each new shortcut or remove it from the desktop.

Comment: This doesn't allow me to still have a usable desktop while also completely avoiding the details of the question. I'm only concerned about shortcuts.

Comment: If deleting (or hiding) .lnk foles from you rdesktop, just schedule a task deleting those files, triggered from startup and repeated every 1 or 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I have an easy way to do it.

Go to your `File Explorer` (`ctr` + `e`) and right-click the `desktop folder`. Next, click on `properties` and go to `security tab`, then click on `edit` and change the permission to `deny` for the users.

> DENY

Then click `apply` and `okay`. NOW YOU'RE READY!

Comment: That also makes it hard to use the desktop for shortcuts, folders and files that you actually want to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

Our network spawns at least two shortcuts approximately every hour, which I despise. If I leave them alone, they just reside where they are, but if I delete them they come back within a couple of hours. There are also about a dozen other shortcuts they force onto our desktops which cannot be deleted by users at all. For the un-delete-able shortcuts, I conned an admin into creating an Unused Shortcuts folder and moving ALL of the unwanted, unused shortcuts into that folder where they only take up one spot on my desktop instead of 20. They're there, but I don't see them. For the two re-spawning shortcuts, I simply moved those to my least used monitor where their unwanted presence creates the least irritation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1172748)